# Cannot access key in dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, nsarray, key

I have an NSDictionary and am trying to access the 'venue' key and assign various keys such as name. I've tried to take the dictionary and access venue with no luck:

```
 NSDictionary *dic = result;
 NSArray *venues1 = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"response.groups.items.venue"];
```

How would I access venue?

```
{
    meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    response =     {
        groups =         (
                        {
                items =                 (
                                        {

                        venue =                         {
                            name = "Ping Tom Memorial Park";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access it in this way

```
NSDictionary *venues1 = dic[@"response"][@"groups"][0][@"items"][0][@"venue"];
```

be careful that groups, items are arrays and venue is a dictionary instead of array.